# Time tracker macro for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I bet the solution to this is easy but I can't just wrap my head around this. So basically this is how my table looks

| start_time (A1) | stop_time (B1) |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
|  |  |

I want a macro that when it's clicked, it will go to cell A2 and put the current local time there. Clicked again, it goes to cell B2 and put the local time there. Clicked again, it goes to cell A3, then B3, A4, etc.

I think the logic is

- Check cell Ax for blank:

  - If yes, insert the time
  - If no, move to cell Bx. Is it blank?

    - If yes, insert the time
    - if no, insert the time in cell A(x+1)

I just don't know how to actually put this in code. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `IsEmpty` can check if a cell is blank. Also see [how to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).

Comment: I know how to check it but I don't know how to automatically select the next row if the row being checked doesn't have any blank value anymore

Comment: The last row (as long as it's greater than one) will *never* be blank.

Comment: Apologies but since I'm not a super VB user, could you please help providing the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TimeStamp()

    Dim row As Long
    Dim col As Long
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        If IsEmpty(.Cells(1, 1)) Then
            row = 1
            col = 1
        Else
            row = .Columns(1).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
            If IsEmpty(.Cells(row, 2)) Then
                col = 2
            Else
                row = row + 1
                col = 1
            End If
        End If
        .Cells(row, col).Value = Now
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas for saving my life. This works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

We check the number of cells used. If Ax is greater than Bx, then we write the value in Bx. If not, we set it on Ax.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub SetTime()

    Dim lastARow As Integer
    Dim lastBRow As Integer
    
    lastARow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastBRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If lastARow > lastBRow Then
        Cells(lastBRow + 1, 2) = Now
    Else
        Cells(lastARow + 1, 1) = Now
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This didn't work for me but thanks though

Comment: Just tried it and it works. Can you elaborate on what part is not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @aklassen maybe because you're not explicitly referencing the sheet?

Comment: @aklassen: My true data is not in the exact cell like my example. Start _time was actually at cell G17 and stop_time at H17. SO i changed your macro

Option Explicit
Public Sub SetTime()

    Dim lastARow As Integer
    Dim lastBRow As Integer
    
    lastARow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    lastBRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    
    If lastARow > lastBRow Then
        Cells(lastBRow + 1, 8) = Now
    Else
        Cells(lastARow + 1, 7) = Now
    End If

End Sub

And they just keep inserting the time in the start_time column only